# Passing regular expressions though URL encoding

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, nancy

I'm trying to pass regular expressions from client to server, using Angular JS client side and Nancy FX server side. I'm having a particular problem with the '+' character. I'm currently explicitly encoding '+' as '%2B' client side:

```
    this.getMatchingPoints = function (stringMatch) {
        console.log("Application Points Service: getPointsMatching('" + stringMatch + "')");
        /* we have a particular problem with the character '+' in regular expressions, since
         * encodeURIComponent ignores it, and urldecoders treat it as a space. So it must be
         * manually url encoded after passing the rest of the string to encodeURIcomponent */
        var encodedPattern = encodeURIComponent(stringMatch).replace('+', '%2B');
        return $http.get('/Json/PointsMatching/' + encodedPattern);
    };
```

...but it's still received as a space server side.

In a sense this doesn't enormously matter, given that any instance of, for example, '[A-Z]+' in a regular expression can be replaced by '[A-Z][A-Z]*'; or, alternatively, I could write my own special encoder for '+' client-side with my own special decoder server side.

But I wonder whether anyone has encountered this problem before, and, if so, how they solved it?

Comment: Well, I maligned the writers of encodeURIComponent; it does indeed correctly replace pluses ('+') with '%2B'.

The problem is at the Nancy side of the world. This is curious because the C# HttpUtility.UrlDecode library function correctly decodes '%2B' as '+'.

Comment: Have you tried self-hosting with OWIN instead of the old Nancy Self Host? The OWIN way shouldn't suffer from double encoding as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more investigation shows that this is a deep and hard to resolve bug in Nancy FX, which the developers know about; see [here](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1280).

My workaround is, given that spaces are not valid characters in the particular context I'm working in, to replace all spaces with pluses server side:

```
        /* <summary>
         *  Return a JSON formatted document comprising a list of all those application points whose 
         *  names match the regular expression.
         *  </summary>
         *  <remarks>
         *  <para>This entry point is expected to be invoked with the pattern as the final element in the path
         *  (i.e. <code>/Json/PointsMatching/pattern_here</code>). This variant cannot cope with either slashes
         *  or backslashes in the pattern, even if they're URL encoded.</para>
         *  </remarks>
         *  <param name="pattern">A regular expression.</param>
         *  <returns>A JSON formatted document comprising a list of all those application points whose 
         *  names match the regular expression.</returns>
         */
        this.Get["/PointsMatching/{pattern}"] = _ =>
        {
            string pattern = (string)_.pattern;
            /* THIS IS A HACK! The URL decoder used by Nancy decodes both '+' and '%2B' as ' ', which
             * rather defeats the point of url encoding. However, we don't normally use spaces in
             * application point names (although it would be valid to do so), so it's fairly save to
             * replace all spaces in patterns with pluses. */
            pattern = pattern.Replace(" ", "+");

            return this.WithValidUser<string>(pattern, InterestRegistry.Instance.GetPointsMatching);
        };
```

This is obviously ugly and not a general purpose solution, but it works for now.